# Bug en la cuenta de etiquetas

Tags: bug, estado-por-diseño

Uso la aplicación de StackExchange para iOS y si voy a mi perfil de SOes veo esto:

[image: Perfil de Alvaro Montoro en iOS]

Mientras que si voy al perfil en el sitio web, la cuenta es diferente:

[image: Perfil de Alvaro Montoro en web]

Los números no coinciden y no por 1 ó 2, en algunos casos es por 50-40. Por ejemplo:

```
ETIQUETA        | APP  | WEB
----------------+------+------
JavaScript      | 201  | 176
HTML            | 154  | 113
jQuery          | 109  | 97
HTML5           | 103  | 60
```

¿Es esto un bug?¿O es que se están contando cosas diferentes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la web son los votos recibidos por respuestas.

En la aplicación mobile son los votos de preguntas + respuestas.

---

Si ves el tooltip en la web:

[image: puntuacion]

aparece también la información de preguntas. `177 + 25 = 202` que es lo que deberías ver ahora en [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) en el celular.

Acá se detalla que en la aplicación mobile se muestra la suma de preguntas + respuestas: [Tag score calculation wrong in Android App](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212315/304899)

Comment: Eso explicaría la diferencia en votos; voy a hacer las cuentas a ver si así coinciden.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro No hace falta hacer las cuentas... incluí el link que lo dice